# How does event handler works in javascript?

Tags: javascript, function, events, closures, handler

the functions execution is done and wont ever be called again but still I can access the event handler inside it

```
(function () {
 const header = document.querySelector('h1');
 header.style.color = 'red';
 header.addEventListener('click', function () {
  this.style.color = this.style.color === 'blue' ? 'red' : 'blue';
 });
})();
```

Comment: so events attached to dom elements alwasy stay active until they are remvoed?

Answer (score 0):

In your JavaScript code, your are attaching an event handler to an object in the DOM.

Since the element doesn't disappear, after your IIFE ran, the handler is still attached to it, even though your `header` variable doesn't exist anymore.

```js
document.querySelector("h1").click()
console.log("color after first click: " + document.querySelector("h1").style.color);

(function () {
 const header = document.querySelector('h1');
 header.style.color = 'red';
 header.addEventListener('click', function () {
  this.style.color = this.style.color === 'blue' ? 'red' : 'blue';
 });
})();

document.querySelector("h1").click()
console.log("color after second click: " + document.querySelector("h1").style.color)

document.querySelector("h1").click()
console.log("color after third click: " + document.querySelector("h1").style.color)
```

```html
<h1>Test</h1>
```

You can see this even better if you attach the event listener via the `onclick` property, since event added via `addEventListener` can't easily be accessed afterwards:

```js
console.log(document.querySelector("h1").onclick); // -> null

(function () {
 const header = document.querySelector('h1');
 header.style.color = 'red';
 header.onclick =  function () {
  this.style.color = this.style.color === 'blue' ? 'red' : 'blue';
 }
})();

document.querySelector("h1").click()

console.log(document.querySelector("h1").onclick) // -> your function
```

```html
<h1>Test</h1>
```

If you want to remove an event listener from an element, you have to have a reference to the function you attached, otherwise the `removeEventListener` method will not work.